# How to display base and derived class properties on the same level in QuickWatch

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, interface

I have defined the follow base and derived classes with their respective interfaces as per:

```
public class SomeModule : ModBase, ISomeModule
{
    public Parameter2<int> Param3 { get; set; } = new Parameter2<int>();
}

public interface ISomeModule : IModBase
{        
    Parameter2<int> Param3 { get; set; }
}

public class ModBase : IModBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parameter2<int> Param1 { get; set; } = new Parameter2<int>();
    public Parameter2<bool> Param2 { get; set; } = new Parameter2<bool>();

    public Parameter2<bool> HiddenParam { get; set; } = new Parameter2<bool>();
}

public interface IModBase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    Parameter2<int> Param1 { get; set; }
    Parameter2<bool> Param2 { get; set; }
    Parameter2<bool> HiddenParam { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a SomeModule object instance, base properties and derived ones are disociated as per following diagram (ie. I need to look from within the base object to be able to see Param3):
[image]

Is there a way to have all properties visible from the derived object (without having to expand the base object to see Param3) as per:
[image]

---

Edit

As suggested by Alex - Tin Le, a debug string can be added in order to list all the properties in one same location. Not quite what I was after, but a nice work around.
Here is an example using "GetProperties()" to list all the derived class properties in one same place:

```
public class SomeModule : ModBase, ISomeModule
{
    public List<string> DebugString => base.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    public Parameter2<int> Param3 { get; set; } = new Parameter2<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "visible". From the coding point of view, all properties are visible (not private), so the below code works fine.

```
   child.Param1 = ....
   child.Param2 = ....
   child.Param3 = ....
```

However, if you want it to be "visible" on that watch inspector, I don't think you can do that. However, there is a trick (work around). I guess you got multi level nested, so you're tired of expanding each level. You can add below code

```
public class SomeModule : ModBase, ISomeModule
{
    public Parameter2<int> Param3 { get; set; } = new Parameter2<int>();
    public string DebugString => $"Param1: {Param1.ToString()}, Param2: {Param2.ToString()}, Param3: {Param3.ToString()}";
}
```

So every time you inspect 1 object, you see everything in 1 place.

Comment: Yes, there are many levels of nesting in my system. Your suggested DebugString gives the following output: Param1: Scratch.Parameter2`1[System.Int32], Param2: Scratch.Parameter2`1[System.Boolean], Param3: Scratch.Parameter2`1[System.Int32]. Not too useful as is, but I get the idea, thanks :-)

Comment: Ya, you need to convert your param to a readable string. I cant suggest how to convert since you dont provide your param class.

Comment: Glad that it helps

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly there is no build in way.
It is how the inspector is build and there is no setting for this.
However if you're willing and it's not too much work for you, you could probably create an vs-extension to accomplish that.